# User-dependent file content

Tags: linux, operating-system, filesystems, fuse, chroot

For some unfortunate reasons, I have to convert a proprietary and binary library from a one-user per workstation to a multi-user per workstation setup.

**Current setup**. A user uses a program linked against a library. This library reads a system wide configuration file (using an hard-coded path, ie /usr/local/thelib/main.conf ) which itself contains several paths to several working directories. The wdir are themselves containing a bunch of user data files.

**Desired outcome**. Being able to manage several users on the same workstation. Of course, a user shall not be able to read nor alter any other user's data through the library, which should be taken care of by unix rights if I manage to feed the library a different working directory for each user.

The library might be used by several users at the same time so ln-ing the configuration file in /usr/local at runtime is not an option.

I was thinking of using FUSE in order to provide a different content for the file /usr/local/thelib/main.conf, depending on an environnement variable or the current unix user. The environnement var would then be used as a switch inside the code producing the configuration file.

I'm confortable using Python, Perl or C.

The workstation is running an up-to-date GNU/Linux Debian or Ubuntu distribution with a pretty recent kernel.

So. What do you think :

- would you use FUSE ?
- would you produce another kind of wrapper - using chroot(2) was suggested below per janneb - ?
- use something else allowed by Linux ?

I kinda know that I would be able to produce something functional but I'll get the community advice since I don't want to reinvent the wheel right now.

Thanks.
Florian

Comment: By any chance, does the configuration file allow relative paths ? If so, you could probably hack something which changes the CWD before using the library.

Comment: If the path `/usr/local/thelib/main.conf` really is hard-coded in the library, that's a pretty terrible design decision on the part of whoever wrote it.

Comment: @David: a lot of free software actually does that with /etc, but it does not matter as recompilation is easy and the path can easily be modified.

Comment: @Pierre: but most of those programs are things like servers, of which there should normally only be one instance, running as root, installed on the system. Besides, for those programs, `/etc` is a pretty standard path for configuration files. Hardcoding a path in `/usr/local` seems like a very strange choice, though.

Comment: @David: I do agree with the terrible design decision. Unfortunately, the library's maintainer is an untouchable public-sector consortium and any design enhancement request is ignored.

Comment: @Pierre: I tried to strace(1) which paths are actually valid for this file. I can only see one open(2) call for this path, and the library's init function fails if the file does not exists. I would then say that there is no alternative path using a relative path.

Comment: @Pierre : that's a good question. I look into that.

Comment: Woops, deleted my comment by error : was saying « @madflo: I was talking about the paths you set in the config file. »

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could use LD_PRELOAD to load a small stub that intercepts open() calls, and opens  ~/.main.conf (assuming this is a shared object). Then in your application startup routine, check that LD_PRELOAD is set to the correct value, and if not, restart the app with the correct environment.

Comment: It seems to be the best solution. I'm going to write this wrapper right now. Thank you !

Answer (score 2):

A simple way would be for the app to call chroot() before calling the library init function(s). E.g. if you chroot into $HOME/theapp then each user can have a private own config file in $HOME/theapp/usr/local/thelib/main.conf as well as private working dirs somewhere under $HOME/theapp.

Comment: Note that `chroot(2)` requires root privileges, so you would also need to setuid root your app and drop privileges ASAP.

Comment: I agree with the fact that it does seems like the simplest solution at this time. A good old chroot(2).